ArcGIS WAB Dev Edition - update widget source layers after Add Data
I have a WAB Dev Edition app that includes the Add Data widget as well as versions of the NearMe and eSearch widgets. Has anyone implemented code to incorporate featureLayers added via Add Data into the source data list for another widget, like eSearch?
I have found a few obliquely related examples, but wondering if anyone has seen something more directly related.
